# Cannot access EKS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I have a `aws-auth` config map like this. In the `mapUsers` section I wanted to add another user with master permissions:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/eks-nodegroup-service-role
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/k8s-admin
    username: k8s-admin
    groups:
    - system:masters
  mapAccounts: |
    - "XXX"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
```

But I still get an error when using `k8s-admin` user: `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`.

[EDIT]
I've added `mapAccounts`. Now the error is:
`Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/k8s-admin" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default`

Answer (score 0):

```
mapUsers: |
  - userarn: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/k8s-admin
  username: k8s-admin
  groups:
  - system:masters
```

You statement above is incorrect, try:

```
...
mapUsers: |
  - userarn: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/k8s-admin
    username: k8s-admin
    groups:
    - system:masters
...
```